# Sentry ignores --config path

Tags: config, sentry

I got Sentry (6.0.6) to work, at least when I do `sentry start` it works. However, I don't want the default config location.

Easy enough theoretically. I moved the config file and use

```
sentry start --config=/new/path/sentry.conf.py
```

... as found [here](http://sentry.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cli/). But:

```
ValueError: Configuration file does not exist at '/home/username/.sentry/sentry.conf.py'
```

...which is the default location, not the one I'm passing.

Why is the `--config` being ignored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace

```
sentry start --config=/new/path/sentry.conf.py
```

with

```
sentry --config=/new/path/sentry.conf.py start
```